# How do I git clone a GIT repository that is on a remote server to which I have SSH key access?

Tags: git

I can connect to my server via ssh@xx.xx.xx.xx without a password.

I have a project under GIT on the server at:
/home/myuser/project

How do I clone this locally to whereby I can make commits etc locally and then push to this server?

As you can tell I am a GIT newbie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git clone ssh@xx.xx.xx.xx:/home/myuser/project`

However, if /home/myuser is $HOME that can be abbreviated to `git clone ssh@xx.xx.xx.xx:project`